# как вставить gif в html?

Tags: html, bootstrap4, img, gif

Всем привет подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такой блок при помощи бустрап? Левая и правая картинки gif. Посоветуйте как лучше, через тег img или задать их как background? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Делайте при помощи img, background не нужен.

если изображения разные по размеру используете стиль  на тег img `object-fit: cover`

Answer (score 1):

можно так, как вам угодно. Советую делать так, а не через background